# Deploy ASP.NET webservice on Local LAN

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have just develop a webservice on VS2012 and Build Successful.
The link like:

```
http://localhost:55555/eTradingWebservice.asmx
```

But when i change this by:

```
http://127.0.0.1:55555/eTradingWebservice.asmx
```

-> it return BAD REQUEST - Invalid Hostname on my Google Chrome
On the machine is same problem (BAD REQUEST)

I have checked my hosts file, it contain string:

```
127.0.0.1 locahost
```

I try to check IIS service, try with this link:

```
http://localhost
http://127.0.0.1
```

every is OK. I deploy my project on IIS8 with VS2012

Comment: btw - 127.0.0.1 locahost actually means that when you use localhost it will get mapped to the IP address of 127.0.0.1. (its not the other way around 127.0.0.1 does not get sent as localhost)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by IIS Express not having any binding for 127.0.0.1 for your web service project and only having binding for localhost in the applicationhost.config file.  You need to add the 127.0.0.1 binding in order to get this to work.

The file is locate in [My Documents]\IISExpress\Config folder and you need to search for your project bindings and add the 127.0.0.1 as I have done in an example from my machine:

```
<site name="MVCApp" id="15">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Projects\MVCApp" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55555:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55555:127.0.0.1" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

You may also need to open that up using netsh:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:55555/  user=everyone
```

when you are done you can remove this with

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:55555/
```

Take a look at [Using IISExpress for addresses other than localhost!](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2012/11/06/Using-IISExpress-for-addresses-other-than-localhost.aspx) by 'But it works on my PC!'

which recommends a final step to run IISExpress with administrative privileges/ You can do this either by running VS as administrtor or by opening a PowerShell prompt with administrative privileges and running the command

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe /site:MyWebProject
```

Comment: I have added <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55555:127.0.0.1" /> but it get error when deploy in VS2012. Error is "Failed to register URL http://127.0.0.1/ for site. Access denied!!

Comment: You should be able to run VS as an administrator and have it pick up the change - failing that swap the order of the two lines..